# Return value from a column based on the value of a second column for a certain range on a third column in Excel 2016 - Power Pivots

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Attached in the following image [Example of 2 Bus Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZR4E.png)
I have an Excel table showing 2 bus services (B1 and B2), covering 6 and 13 stops respectively and the times a bus will pass by each one of them (column C).

What I need to get on column D is the Scheduled Start time of each bus service, that is the number from column C (in red) corresponding to the first stop of that service (column B = 1) for every service (range of values in column A = B1, then B2).

Comment: just `=SUMIFS($C$2:C2,$B$2:B2,1,$A$2:A2,A2)` in D2 and copy down (set format to time)... or D2 with `=C2` and in D3 `=IF(B3=1,C3,D2)` and copy down D3.........

Comment: That was quick!! Thanks Dirk!! Unfortunately I cannot use SUMIFS in PowerPivot environment... I have found this but having troubles on how to apply it: http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2009/12/powerpivot-dax-calculate-is-a-supercharged-sumif/